getting"api error AccessDenied: Access Denied" when making s3 bucket using terraform
I'm making s3 bucket with terraform to use it for static web site.
But I'm getting 'api error AccessDenied" error when I try to make s3 bucket.
The error message is below.
I searched for how to solve itbut I couldn't find clear answer.
enter image description here
And my main.tf code for s3 bucket is below.
I want to solve this error. I know I can just make s3 bucket manually in aws websites.
But I want to make it using terraform.
And if there is any good document or sources to solve it, I'm glad to hear that.
#s3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "songbucket202404" {
  bucket = "songbucket202404"
  tags = {
      Name = "songbucket202404"
    }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "SongBucket_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.songbucket202404.id
  acl = "public-read"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "playlist_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.songbucket202404.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
         "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.songbucket202404.arn}/*"
      },
    ]
  })

}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "SongWeb"{
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.songbucket202404.id
    key = "index.html"
    source = "frontend/web/index.html"
}

